# Any Rails scaffold data types that generate radio buttons in the _form.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffolding

For instructional purposes, I'd like to generate scaffolds which showcase radio buttons. You can generate a scaffolding with checkboxes with:

```
rails generate scaffold Person name:string honest:boolean
```

`boolean` data types create checkboxes for the _form.html.erb file used when creating or editing people above. Is there anything that creates radio buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not using the default scaffold generator. Each attribute type (integer, string, boolean etc) defaults to *one* field type. See [rails/generators/generated_attributes.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/67ee6c38b9b112eabe37d5869c23210b9ebf453c/railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb) for how it is implemented.

If you still want to automatically create radio-buttons for the boolean values, you may have to override the default scaffold generator. [Here's some documentation on how to do that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), though I recommend that you change your `check_box` fields to `radio_button` fields manually.